# My program turns a spreadsheet into an Excel-file. But it only works for one user

Tags: excel, oauth, google-apps-script, google-docs-api, google-account

I've made a larger (1000+ lines of code) App Script. It works great, for me. No other user can run it. I want them to be able to run it as well, and I can not figure out why they can't.

The problem occurs on this part:

```
var id = 'A_correct_ID_of_a_Google_Spreadsheet';
var SSurl = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(SSurl+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=xls',googleOAuth_('docs',SSurl)).getBlob();
var spreadsheet = DocsList.createFile(doc);
```

The function (and structure) was published here: [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542907/google-app-script-cant-attach-spreadsheet-to-email)

```
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {  
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

I can't see any reason why the program only would run for one user. All the files are shared between all the users and ownership have been swapped around.

Comment: Have you tried deploying the application as "Anyone, even anonymous" or "Sign-In required" instead of "Just Me"?

Comment: This oauth 1 built-in support does not work for web-apps. Your users need to run this from a spreadsheet (like a menu or button) or you'll have to develop support for oauth 2 in your script (it's not built-in). There's some code examples already out there.

Comment: This script runs from a Speadsheet (Google form-answersheet) from a menu-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a script uses oAuth (googleOAuth_(name,scope) in you case) it needs to be authorized from the script editor, independently from the other authorization that the user grands with the "normal" usual procedure.
This has been the object of an [enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=677) for quite a long time and has no valid workaround as far as I know.

So, depending on how your script is deployed (in a SS or a Doc or as webApp) you might find a solution or not... if, as suggested in the first comment on your post, you run this from a webapp you can deploy it to run as yourself and allow anonymous access and it will work easily, but in every other case your other users will have to open the script editor and run a function that triggers the oAuth authorization process.

Comment: When I run the script (in scipteditor or from spreadsheet) it will work until the row:
    var doc = UrlFet...Blob();
There are no errors, even with a try{...}catch(e){...} around it.

Comment: To be completely honest I didn't see the getBlob()..., the data returned by the urlfetch is already a blob so it is indeed not necessary. Sorry for not having told you in the first place.